# How to make different regions of image into buttons (swift/xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a map and I want to turn different regions of it into clickable elements. I know I could just splice up the map using photoshop and turn each region I want into a button individually, but that feels a bit hacky to me and I don't know if the aspect ratio of everything would stay the same from device to device when I piece the puzzle together. What is the best way to take a single image and divide it up into several complexly shaped clickable areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most general-purpose solution is probably to make the entire view (image view) clickable by attaching a tap gesture recognizer to it and then interpreting the tap gesture.

I'd suggest creating a custom subclass of UIView that has an image view inside it, attaches a tap gesture recognizer, and responds to the messages from the tap gesture recognizer to figure out which region was tapped.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! Using that method do you think it'd be feasible to figure out which region was tapped perfectly, or would it be hard to configure that to such a high level of accuracy?

Comment: @Dal You'll have to store somewhere a list of normalized points to define the path of every region. When the user taps your view, you just have to test your paths to know in which one the tap was made (using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains). The more points you have in each path, the more accurate you are

Comment: It should be easy to detect taps with more accuracy than the accuracy of the user's finger. (Finger taps are imprecise by their nature.) There are various ways to detect taps. You could use a rectangular grid, An arbitrary set of retangles. you could use a set of points and radii, or you could use a set of `UIBezierPaths` and the `UIBezierPath` `contains(_:)` method to detect taps in irregular shapes.

Comment: Okay perfect! I didn't know I could make a list of points like that, that'll definitely work, thanks guys

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again, this is going so much better than I thought it would!